# Do Apple and Google Play Charge Per App Submission?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, google-play

Apologies if this has been asked before but I couldn't find the answer after searching.

I have a news website in development that will have a different site for every country. Each one of these sites will require its own country specific news app. I know about the registration fees for an iOS & Google developer account but does anyone know if this fee will allow me to submit multiple apps or is it a pay per app submission deal?

Comment: google charges once only not for each app, they charges one time for an account and you can publish many apps from that account

Comment: Welcome to SO. First search you problem then ask question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have developer account of Apple/Google, you can upload any number of apps there without  pay anthing more.

In case of apple you have to renew your account once in a year and in case of google, it is one time fees.